# <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/"><!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">

Tags: svg

**HTMLへSVGファイルを読み込んでいるのですが、**
・下記だと表示されて、

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_ai "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
]>
<svg
```

---

・下記では表示されません

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
<svg
```

---

**ENTITYの部分は何を意味しているのでしょうか？**
・nsは名前空間の略？
・この部分を省略すると、なぜ表示されなくなるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<svg` 以降の中身が書いてないので推量になりますが、`<!ENTITY ...>` は[実体宣言](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-entity-decl)です。1つ目の !ENTITY は実体参照 `&ns_flows;` で呼び出す内容を定義していて、実体宣言なしで実体参照が使われるとエラーとなります。